# OpenAPI generator Java Client SE

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-maven-plugin, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I've an OperAPI like this, with content "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" that i must use (the external API to implement support only that):

```
/token:
 post:
  operationId: retrieveToken
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        schema:
          title: GenerateTokenRequest
          type: object
          properties:
            grant_type:
              type: string
            client_id:
              type: string
```

The OpenAPI Generator Maven's plugin creates a request class "GenerateTokenRequest" for the schema object but in API implementation class it doesn't use. It generate a method with all requested fields as a list of parameter. The method is this:

```
 public GenerateTokenResponse retrieveToken(String grantType, String clientId, String clientSecret, String scope) throws ApiException {
    ApiResponse<GenerateTokenResponse> resp = retrieveTokenWithHttpInfo(grantType, clientId, clientSecret, scope);
    return resp.getData();
}
```

So, in this case the request class "GenerateTokenRequest" is generated but never used. Anyone can say me why? There is an alternative way for using my request class? Can I change something in OpenAPI file structure? Or there is a way to avoid the generation of the request class?

**EDIT**: Solved! The service i wanted to define was an OAuth2 authentication service so i've configured a securitySchemas of type "oauth2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**! The service i wanted to define was an OAuth2 authentication service so i've configured a securitySchemas of type "oauth2"

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

by

```
application/json or application/xml
```

Comment: I must use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" because the external API that i have to implement support only that Content-Type

Comment: What do you mean by "support only that Content-Type"? the content type is defined by the client , so the client could change that

Comment: It means that if i change Content-Type to "application/json" i'll receive a "400 Bad Request" error. This because "application/json" wants a json body for a POST api, instead with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" i must use a form-data format

Comment: I add a new answer who to avoid the generation of the request class.
Doesn't solve your question then?

Comment: no, unfortunally it generates a "RequestBody" class

Answer (score 0):

```
paths:
  /token:
    post:
      operationId: retrieveToken
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                grant_type:
                  type: string
                client_id:
                  type: string
```

If you use that structure, no request class "GenerateTokenRequest" will be generated, only the API

Comment: no, unfortunally it generates a "RequestBody" class